# How to get git repo between commit change file list?

Tags: git, deployment

I want to make incremental updating with git repo！
Server saved a file (repo-commit-version.txt)

Example：（7ed656f60ae0bb2a55ed632d29999a3a45313deb）

now want to auto deploy the last repo version to Server

how to get (last repo version with in server repo-commit-version.txt ) change files[modified/create/delete] list?

git log?git diff?~~~

Comment: Your explanation is not clear to me. Do you mean "last commit" when you say "last repo"? Could you please clarify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking, but it sounds like you either want to know what files a commit changes:

```
git diff --stat COMMIT_ID --
```

Or, what has changed between to commits:

```
git diff --stat SRC_COMMIT_ID DST_COMMIT_ID --
```

For example, it the Python nose repository, I get this:

```
$ git diff --stat release_1.3.0 HEAD --

 AUTHORS                                         |  1 +
 CHANGELOG                                       |  7 ++
 doc/.templates/indexsidebar.html                | 18 +----
 doc/usage.rst                                   |  5 ++
 .../test_multiprocess/multiprocess.rst          |  2 +-
 functional_tests/support/issue649/test.py       |  9 +++
 functional_tests/support/issue680/test.py       |  3 +
 functional_tests/support/issue700/test.py       |  4 +
 functional_tests/support/issue720/test.py       |  6 ++
 functional_tests/test_failuredetail_plugin.py   | 14 ++++
 functional_tests/test_issue_649.py              | 18 +++++
 functional_tests/test_xunit.py                  | 32 ++++++++
 nose/commands.py                                | 11 ++-
 nose/config.py                                  |  5 +-
 nose/core.py                                    |  9 ++-
 nose/failure.py                                 |  3 +-
 nose/importer.py                                |  2 +-
 nose/plugins/capture.py                         | 22 +-----
 nose/plugins/debug.py                           | 15 ++--
 nose/plugins/doctests.py                        |  2 +
 nose/plugins/failuredetail.py                   |  8 +-
 nose/plugins/xunit.py                           | 75 +++++++++----------
 nose/pyversion.py                               | 65 +++++++++++++++-
 nose/util.py                                    |  2 +-
 unit_tests/support/doctest/.gitignore           |  1 +
 .../support/doctest/noname_wrapped.not_py       |  6 ++
 unit_tests/support/doctest/noname_wrapper.py    | 12 +++
 unit_tests/support/init_prefix_bug/__init__.py  |  1 +
 .../support/init_prefix_bug/__init__not.py      |  1 +
 unit_tests/test_core.py                         | 33 +++++++-
 unit_tests/test_doctest_no_name.py              | 34 +++++++++
 unit_tests/test_importer.py                     | 10 +++
 unit_tests/test_xunit.py                        | 34 ---------
 33 files changed, 344 insertions(+), 126 deletions(-)
```

Notice that some paths have been truncated because of my screen width.  You can control the widths using parameters to the `--stat` option.  You can run `git help diff` or look at the [diff man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) for more information.